# Auto load kbd file on keyboard connect

Tags: configuration, keyboard, xkb

I have created a keyboard layout file (`my_keyboard.kbd`) specific for my keyboard.  I load it manually using `xkbcomp my_keyboard.kbd $DISPLAY` which works fine.

Currently, some other (the default/standard layout) gets loaded each time my keyboard gets connected to the computer.  I would like to autoload my layout whenever my keyboard gets connected.  It would be okay as well if connecting any keyboard would trigger loading my layout.

How can I achieve that?  TIA.

EDIT: I am running the standard Ubuntu using Gnome and my keyboards are connected the normal way via USB.

Comment: As usual `udev` rules !

Comment: @cbhihe Any link for newbies to this topic?  Never used it before.

Comment: I've looked into it and think it is not the right way to go.  Using the udev approach a script is run to execute that explicit loading of the keyboard config for a specific session.  This raises several new problems like how do I pass the current DISPLAY and Xauthority etc. to this script?  This way I expect trouble when reconnecting the keyboard during xlock or while being logged out.  No, I want the keyboard to be recognized by the system directly.  Currently, the system loads some keyboard default; I want to make it act more specific and understand that this keyboard has a different config.

Comment: I specified in OP that I’m loading the config via `xkbcomp … $DISPLAY`, so this is for user-session loads of the config.  I’m searching for a way to make the system use my config in general when the keyboard shows up, not just temporarily for the currently running user session.  And there must be a way of course.  I want to add my keyboard layout to the list of many layouts which are for sure already existing in the keyboard system, for the many existing keyboards.  Even if the keyboard is connected not using USB, that should work.

Comment: Fair enough. So you  might want to explore linking a `systemd` service execution, just after your X server has finished getting to speed at boot, making sure that the keymap compilation with your X-DISPLAY as destination is NOT linked to any user session.   May I suggest that you add your last comment to your OP by editing your post ? It is both useful and necessary information.